# How can I use methods from first VC in second VC?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller with methodA that returns something like a `CGSize`. I would like to use this method in another view controller. How can I set it up so that I can access it like an instance method? Or it is the better way to make custom class to calculations?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

```
@interface Utils : NSObject
+ (CGSize) getSizeFromSomething;
@end
```

When you need to use it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
CGSize s = [Utils getSizeFromSomething];
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create custom class (may be sub class of `NSObject`).

```
//.h file
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "CommonService.h"
#import "URL.h"
#import "API.h"

@interface BrandService : NSObject

-(NSDictionary*)getBrands:(NSString*)params;
-(NSDictionary*)getBrandProducts:(NSString*)params;
-(int)getBrandCount;

@end
```

The implement the methods in `.m` file. And then you can call them by careating an instance of that class. You can make custom class to calculations.

Hope this helps.. :)